# foreign key entity framework issue

Tags: c#, .net

I have one parent child entity :

```
public class Transaction
{
  public int TransactionId {get; set;}
  public int? OrderId {get; set;}
  public virtual Order Order {get; set;}

} 

public class Order 
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual List<OrderItems> OrderItems {get; set;}
}

public class OrderItem
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Item {get; set;}
  public virtual int OrderId {get; set;}
  public virtual Order Order {get; set;}
}
```

the context is as following :

```
   modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>( )
            .HasKey( x => x.TransactionId )
            .ToTable( "Transactions" );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Transaction>( )
            .HasOptional( x => x.Order )
            .WithMany( )
            .HasForeignKey( t => t.OrderId );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>( )
            .HasKey( o => o.Id )
            .ToTable("Orders");

        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>( )
            .HasKey( i => i.Id )
            .ToTable( "OrderItems" );


        modelBuilder.Entity<OrderItem>( )
            .HasRequired( x => x.Order )
            .WithMany( o => o.OrderItems )
            .HasForeignKey( p => p.OrderId );
```

When I try to create a new entity of type Transaction, something like :

```
var transaction = new Transaction 
                   {TransactionId = Guid.NewGuid;
                    Order = new Order {OrderItems = new List<OrderItems>{Item="SunCream"}}};
```

and

```
ctx.Transactions.Add(transaction);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I get

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Transactions_Orders_OrderId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Transactions", table "dbo.Orders", column 'Id'.

What exactly am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to explicitly add the Order object to the ctx object first before you add the transaction.  That way when you call the `.SaveChanges()` the context will know it has to commit the Order first before you commit the Transaction.